# Windows Form won't show with DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, directx

I'm trying to make a media player application with DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback, but when I try to run it, the project builds successfully and the application runs, but the Form doesn't show.  The application just hangs on Application.Run().  However, when I comment out all of the DirectX code, the application runs like it is supposed to.

Here is my code:

```
Video v_Video = null;

void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    v_Video.Size = VideoViewer.Size; //VideoViewer is a PictureBox
    v_Video.Owner = VideoViewer;
}

void PlayButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    v_Video = new Video(File.ReadAllText("VideoLocation.txt") + "\\Video.wmv");
    v_Video.Play();
    PauseButton.BringToFront();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this DLL before. When I attempt to open a media file, Visual Studio throws this exception:

> DLL
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.DirectX\1.0.2902.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.DirectX.dll'
>   is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt
>   to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function
>   since doing so can cause the application to hang.

I suggest you using another library. Take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3dbfb9a3-4e14-41d1-afbb-1790420706fe).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question the best that you could, and not putting me down because I "didn't give enough detail".  Kudos to you! :D